# Adjusting Grid View ChildAspecRatio according to screen size

Tags: layout, dart, flutter

I am developing an app that includes GridView, here is the simplest form of code:

```
return OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
  return RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: refreshList,
    child: new GridView.builder(
      itemCount: dergiler.length,
      gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
          childAspectRatio: 0.7),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Dergielemet(dergiler[index], index),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
});
```

When I use the as childAspectRatio as 0.7 I am getting what I want. Here is the image:

[image])

However, when I try the same code on another device with slightly different screen size, there would be overflow errors because elements of GridView are overflowing each other. Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use the as **childAspectRatio** some thing like this

> MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/980